# How to prevent path from being attached if condition not required? SSIS custom component

Tags: c#, ssis, custom-component

In my custom data flow component, I have overriden the OnOutputPathAttached method. I want outputs to be attached under certain conditions. ie:

```
    public override void OnOutputPathAttached(int outputID)
    {
            if (/*condition*/)
            {
                //do some processing
                base.OnOutputPathAttached(outputID);
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error message");
               //CODE TO STOP OUTPUT FROM BEING ATTACHED???
            }
    }
```

What should I put so that the output isn't attached? For now it shows the error message but still attaches the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that it's too late to stop the user from attaching a path by the time your `OnOutputPathAttached` method is called. (At least, that's how I'm reading the MSDN page on the [AttachPathAndPropagateNotifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.wrapper.idtspath100.attachpathandpropagatenotifications.aspx)  method.)

Your best bet seems to be to return `VS_ISBROKEN` from your [Validate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.wrapper.idtsdesigntimecomponent100.validate.aspx) method, along with raising useful `OnError` events.